# How to create a CMS editable channel section index page?

Tags: sections

If I have a section called 'blog', and its handle is 'blog', and it's a Channel, all of the entries appear under http://mysite.com/blog/{slug} - which is great; but how would I create a page at mysite.dev/blog which is editable in the CMS, with its own fields? I'd like to do this so I can have a CMS editable introduction to the blog section, rather than having to hard-code an introduction into the template that would then list the latest X blog posts.

I can't create a Single called 'blog' because that handle is already taken by the Section itself, so how would I go about this? I'd considered using a Global, but that seems a bit off (it's not global content, it's a singular page's content) not to mention repetative/non-DRY if I had multiple sections to do similar things with, or if there were multiple fields I wanted applying on the overview/landing page. Is there a neater solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a Single called "Blog Overview" and set its URI to "blog" and its "Entry Template" to "blog/index" (your blog listing template).

Then just override the title to "Blog" either by hard coding it in the index template, using an "title override" field, not showing its title etc.

Comment: Or, you could rename the Channel, and let the Single have the title "Blog" uncontested.

Comment: Ah! So treat a Channel as 'Blog Entries' and the overview page Single as 'Blog', then set the channel URLs to be /blog/{slug} while the overview single is /blog - Ok that makes sense! Thank you both :)

Comment: Craft CMS official boilerplate demo have this done as you said in Services and Work sections (adding Services Index and Work Index singles).

Comment: I wish they would handle that differently... Feels messy to need additional section entries to do such a simple task. Especially when as you say what if we've got a multiple sections that function this way. What about creating a page in the channel but click a checkbox that set it to be a listing page?